# What are the benefits of replacing Haskell record with a function

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I was reading this interesting [article](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/12/the-continuation-monad.html) about continuations and I discovered this clever *trick*. Where I would naturally have used a record, the author uses instead a function with a sum type as the first argument.

So for example, instead of doing this

```
data Processor = Processor { processString :: String -> IO ()
                           , processInt :: Int -> IO ()
                           }


processor = Processor (\s -> print $ "Hello "++ s)
                      (\x -> print $ "value" ++ (show x))
```

We can do this:

```
data Arg = ArgString String | ArgInt Int
processor :: Arg -> IO ()
processor (ArgString s) = print "Hello" ++ s
processor (ArgInt x) = print "value" ++ (show x)
```

Apart from being clever, what are the benefits of it over a simple record ?
Is it a common pattern and does it have a name ?

Comment: I _think_ the correct term for this is "Church encoding". I'm not sure what the benefits are.

Comment: `(A+B)->C` is exactly all pairs of `A->C` and `B->C` by definition of `A+B` - i.e. `A+B` is such an object with the universal property that for any `A->C` and `B->C` has the unique arrows `A->(A+B)` (`Left`) and `B->(A+B)` (`Right`) such that the diagram commutes.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's just a simple isomorphism. In ADT algebraic:

`IO()`<sup>`String`</sup> × `IO()`<sup>`Int`</sup>
≅ `IO()`<sup>`String`+`Int`</sup>

The obvious benefit of the RHS is perhaps that it only contains `IO()` once – DRY FTW.

Comment: The value `processor` from the first example and the function `processor` from the second are equivalent, but the type `Processor` is more general.  It would allow you to build values that can do more than print a value, while the second example limits you to just a single set of actions.  You could conceivably have `[Processor]` where each value in the list has different behavior.  The length of this list and what goes in it can be decided at runtime, whereas writing a separate top-level function for each as in the second example is fixed at compile time.

Comment: @bheklilr I am not sure whether I understand you. If we would define `newtype P = P (Arg -> IO ())`, what is it then that we cannot do with a values of type `P` that we can do with values of type `Processor`?

Comment: @StefanHoldermans Yes, you could, but that's not in mb14's code.  What I was trying to get at is that defining a data type that holds functions is in general more flexible than just defining functions.

Comment: @bheklilr I see. But I'd argue that it's only a bit more flexible. Sure, one could have instance declarations for `P` that one could not have for just `Arg -> IO ()`—but apart from that, there is not much difference between these types, is there?

Comment: @bheklilr if there is isomorphism, then there is isomorphism. `[Processor]` is isomorphic to `[Arg -> IO()]`

Comment: I understand that they are mathematically isomorph. However that doesn't mean that they are both good (or bad) practice. In imperative languages, it considered bad practice to dispatch functions over argument value.  Ex : `save(file)` and `delete(file)` is prefered over `saveOrDelete(file, true)` and `saveOrDelete(file, false).

Comment: @mb14 In functional languages it's often the exact opposite: I think in Abelson and Sussman's SICP lectures one of them said something like "every good program begins with a case dispatch." The problem here is not that the boolean parameter exists, but rather that it is not an enum. `onFile f (Save data)` and `onFile f Delete` are pretty straightforward to understand even though `onFile` is dispatching on a sum-type.

Comment: @ChrisDrost Which is the point of my question : is it a good or a bad pattern. Dispatching on enum is indeed  tempting and readable , as long as it's a constructor. With `inFile f a` the dispatching on a sum-type is already less obvious.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very loose example but you can see the `Arg` method as being an *initial encoding* and the `Processor` method as being a *final encoding*. They are, as others have noted, of equal power when viewed in many lights; however, there are some differences.

1. Initial encodings enable us to examine the "commands" being executed. In some sense, it means we've sliced the operation so that the input and the output are separated. This lets us choose many different outputs given the same input.
2. Final encodings enable us to abstract over implementations more easily. For instance, if we have two values of type `Processor` then we can treat them identically even if the two have different effects or achieve their effects by different means. This kind of abstraction is popularized in OO languages.
3. Initial encodings enable (in some sense) an easier time adding new functions since we just have to add a new branch to the `Arg` type. If we had many different ways of building `Processor`s then we'd have to update each of these mechanisms.

Honestly, what I've described above is rather stretched. It is the case that `Arg` and `Processor` fit these patterns somewhat, but they do not do so in such a significant way as to really benefit from the distinction. It may be worth studying more examples if you're interested—a good search term is the "expression problem" which emphasizes the distinction in points (2) and (3) above.

Comment: Final encodings is type-safer. Adding a new function , implies adding a new field to Processor and so change the type signature of Processor. Adding a new branch to Arg , just partialize existing functions, which only generates warning (vs error).

Comment: That's not really type safety, though. The equivalent way to dispatch the missing field error with `Processor` is to just set it to `undefined`. If you use something like `vinyl` instead of Haskell's default records you'd have a difference in type safety.

Comment: Having a compilation error because one argument is missing on a constructor , is what I call type safe. Your `undefined` argument stands for "Hakell is not type safe".

Comment: That's a somewhat expanded definition is all. It doesn't really have to do with types and is certainly distinct from the technical definition of ["type safety"](http://jspha.com/posts/six_points_about_type_safety/). That's all fine and I'm not one to argue definitions. Just a note for the wary.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on leftroundabout's response, there is a way of writing functions as Output<sup>Input</sup>, because of *cardinality* (how many things there are). So for example if you think about all of the mappings of the set `{0, 1, 2}` of cardinality 3 to the set `{0, 1}` of cardinality 2, you see that 0 can map to  0 or 1, independent of 1 mapping to 0 or 1, independent of 2 mapping to 0 or 1. When counting the total number of functions we get 2 * 2 * 2 or 2<sup>3</sup>.

In this same way of writing, sum types are written with `+` and product types are written with `*` and there is a cute way to phrase this as Out<sup>In1 + In2</sup> = Out<sup>In1</sup> * Out<sup>In2</sup>; we could write the isomorphism as:

```
combiner :: (a -> z, b -> z) -> Either a b -> z
combiner (za, zb) e_ab = case e_ab of Left a -> za a; Right b -> zb b

splitter :: (Either a b -> z) -> (a -> z, b -> z)
splitter z_eab = (\a -> z_eab $ Left a, \b -> z_eab $ Right b)
```

and we can reify it in your code with:

```
type Processor = Either String Int -> IO ()
```

So what's the difference? There aren't many:

1. The combined form requires both things to have the exact same tail-end. You can't apply `combiner` to something of type `a -> b -> z` since that parses as `a -> (b -> z)` and `b -> z` is not unifiable with `z`. If you wanted to unify `a -> b -> z` with `c -> z` then you have to first uncurry the function to `(a, b) -> z`, which looks like a bit of work -- it's just not an issue when you use the record version.
2. The split form is also a little more concise for application; you just write `fst split a` instead of `combined $ Left a`. But this also means that you can't quite do something like `yz . combined` (whose equivalent is `(yz . fst split, yz . snd split)`) so easily. When you've actually got the `Processor` record defined it might be worth it to extend its kind to `* -> *` and make it a `Functor`.
3. The record can in general participate in type classes more easily than the sum-type-function.
4. Sum types will look more imperative, so they'll probably be clearer to read. For example, if I hand you the pattern `withProcState p () [Read path1, Apply (map toUpper), Write path2]` it's pretty easy to see that this feeds the processor with commands to uppercase path1 into path2. The equivalent of defining processors would look like `procWrite p path2 $ procApply p (map toUpper) $ procRead p path1 ()` which is still pretty clear but not quite as awesome as the previous case.